# SSIS Package getting failed on different user login : Acquire Connection Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am currently working on server where multiple users login with there own credentials to access the database and SSIS packages.
I have created file system based SSIS package to import the data (text file) into the SQL table.

Its working fine on my windows profile. But when other users try to run my created SSIS package from their own windows profile its throwing error

> CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER xC0202009

Note: I have used SQL Authentication admin level credentials while creating SSIS package.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned you are using file based SSIS packages. Do they have associated configurations? For example, XML files, environment variables, etc? And is one of those configurations the connection string?

Comment: No config files. Just SSIS package file. Creds are saved in that package only.

Comment: What is the package protection level?

Comment: Encrypt secure data with user key (2nd option in drop-down)

Comment: OK. Since you are using SQL authentication, the connecting string contains a password, which will be treated as sensitive by SSIS. This will then be encrypted by your user key, which is related to your profile. When another user tries to execute it they do not have your user key, and thus cannot decrypt the sensitive password. I would have expected other users to get an error like "failed to decrypt an XML node". In any case, edit your package and change the protection level to "encrypt sensitive with password". Other users executing the package will need to be given this password.

Comment: I might add that this is of course rather unsecure, since other users, now having the ability to decrypt the sensitive data, can now see the password for an admin level user on the SQL server. This is obviously not great. You would be better off creating a specific login to be used by the package, and which is granted only the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this method.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you, if so I will post it as an answer so others can find it if they have a similar situation in future.